UTAM - how to access data table of a related list LWC in a tab?
I have a related list in a tab set on an object page, and I am trying to use UTAM in Java to access a row in the related list. My LWC is c_individualApplicationsRelatedList in the HTML down below. I can get to the tab content with code like:
RecordHomeFlexipage2 flexipage2 = loader.load(RecordHomeFlexipage2.class);
assert flexipage2 != null;
Tabset tabset = flexipage2.getTabset();
assert tabset != null;
XXXXX iaTabContent = tabset.getActiveTabContent(XXXXX.class);

But I don't know what class to define for XXXXX in the code above. I have tried to define a custom page object to represent the tab content, but I can't seem to find the lightning-datatable element with any CSS selector like "lightning-datatable" in the custom page object. At runtime, it can't find the element.
How can I access the lightning-datatable below?
<flexipage-tab2 slot="tabs" role="tabpanel" id="tab-4" class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-show"
    lwc-e181ppo4iq-host="" aria-labelledby="flexipage_tab4__item">
    <slot lwc-e181ppo4iq="">
        <flexipage-component2 data-component-id="c_individualApplicationsRelatedList"
            data-target-selection-name="c_individualApplicationsRelatedList" lwc-7uq5q81tcsp-host="">
            <slot lwc-7uq5q81tcsp="">
                <c-individual-applications-related-list>
                    <div class="slds-box"><lightning-card lwc-7eubp5ml88f-host="">
                            <article lwc-7eubp5ml88f="" class="slds-card slds-card_narrow" part="card">
                                <div lwc-7eubp5ml88f="" class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
                                    <header lwc-7eubp5ml88f=""
                                    ...
                                    </header>
                                </div>
                                <div lwc-7eubp5ml88f="" class="slds-card__body" part="body">
                                    <slot lwc-7eubp5ml88f="">
                                        <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
                                            <lightning-datatable lwc-392cvb27u8q-host="">

